# Iterate on langchain document items

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I loaded pdf files from a directory and I need to split them to smaller chunks to make a summary. The problem is that I can't iterate on documents object in a for loop and I get an error like this: **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'page_content'**

How can I iterate on my document items to call the summary function for each of them?
Here is my code:

```
# Load the documents

from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
document_directory = "pdf_files"
loader = DirectoryLoader(document_directory)
documents = loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=4000, chunk_overlap=50)

# Iterate on long pdf documents to make chunks (2 pdf files here)
for doc in documents:
  
  # it fails on this line 
  texts = text_splitter.split_documents(doc)    
  chain = load_summarize_chain(llm, chain_type="map_reduce", map_prompt=prompt, combine_prompt=prompt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you want to use a for loop, you can try:

```
for file in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path):
    if file.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdf_path = os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, file)
        loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_path)
        documents.extend(loader.load())
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
chunked_documents = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code on your code.

`texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents=documents)`

the final code is

```
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=4000, chunk_overlap=50)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents=documents)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
loader = DirectoryLoader('/PATH/', glob="**/*.pdf",
                         show_progress=True, use_multithreading=True)
documents = loader.load()
```

And reference the document > https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_loaders/file_directory